# How to extract image path within a tag on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, saxparser

I have a tag called `<descriptor>` which contains some description and an image URL.

Here is my description tag.

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[<img  width="100"   src="http://MYURL/img/news/111/octo/one1.jpg"  align="right" alt="name"/>
</description>
```

I want to extract the image path to display it. I am using the SAX parser for parsing.

Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the CDATA completely like () when you parse in sax, You store as a string. Then parse the string in other function to get the image url path.

getPath(description);
void getpath(String description){

// implements your logic here

}

Comment: i should write this function within the parser?

Comment: not necessary. You use it in the method when u need to get the image path.

Comment: what about the method attributes.getValue("img").will it work ??

Comment: it will work. But u have to parse the description string in another parser. From doing that, U can split it while you need. It will be easy.

Comment: if i will make another parser for description string.then how can i implement attributes.getValue("img"), i mean to say should i write with in the start element method or within the Character method?

Comment: public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts)  {
        // Get the number of attribute
        int length = atts.getLength();

        // Process each attribute
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            // Get names and values for each attribute
            String name = atts.getQName(i);
            String value = atts.getValue(i);

            
           
            String nsUri = atts.getURI(i);

            String src = atts.getLocalName(i);
        }
    } Try like this

Comment: this may helps you,  String str = "<img  width=100 src=http://MYURL/img/news/111/octo/one1.jpg  align=right alt=name/>";
  int startIndex = str.indexOf("src=");
  int endIndex = str.indexOf("align=");
  CharSequence res = str.subSequence(startIndex+4, endIndex);
  System.out.print(res);

Comment: I have many description tags within my XML,and each description tag contains different Image Url's so how process that using the above method??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4189/discussion-between-thiru-and-sagar)

Comment: You store the description in a string while you parse in SAX. u parse that string a method argument and it will return the url path.